# How do I control the selection box or lasso in plotly react?

Tags: typescript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using the basic `<Plot/>` component from react-plotly.js and I know how to get selection box points or lasso points from the PlotSelectionEvent param when the Plot performs an `onSelected` event

[image: selection box]

[image: lasso]

...but I cannot find where to **set** selection box points or lasso points in the Plot via a controllable prop.

Suppose I wanted to capture these selection box or lasso coordinate points and later on if the user clicks a button, I restore that selection box or lasso's location. How could I do that?

I see in the [advanced docs](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md#state-management) you can control the layout, frames, data, and config, but what about selection box or lasso?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selected points by setting the `selectedpoints` attribute of your scatter trace, see https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-selectedpoints. Example:

```
const data = [
  {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
    mode: 'markers',
    type: 'scatter',
    selectedpoints: [1, 3]
  }
]
```

would programmatically select the second and the fourth point.

`selectedpoints` has to be an array of indices, not x and y coordinates. You should be able to get the indices of your selected points from the `onSelected` event.

Comment: +1 So yeah that prop will select the points at those indices, but I’m looking for how to recreate the lasso tool or selection box.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear I'm asking about how to set the selection box and lasso, not the selected points themselves.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I don't think I'll be able to help. Would you mind telling me how to even make a lasso selection in plotly so that these white circles appear? I have never seen that in plotly. What do I have to click in order to see the lasso points highlighted this way?

Comment: If your Plot type is "scatter" then you should see selections at the top of the Plot by default. You'll see a little lasso looking button called Lasso Select. Click that and you'll have lasso enabled.

Comment: I know how to make a lasso selection. I am asking about the appearance of the lasso itself. If you make a lasso selection in a standard plotly chart (https://plotly.com/javascript/line-and-scatter/), the lasso does not have white circles, it consists only of a dashed line.

Comment: My Plot data type is `scattergl`. Maybe that's the reason? I'm not sure.